# Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object

Tags: php, phpword

Добрый день!
Установил библиотеку `PHPWord`,  в шаблон пытаюсь заменить переменные на значения:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$template = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('template.docx');
$template->setValue('family', $data['client']['family']);
$template->setValue('name', $data['client']['name']);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="document.docx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($word, 'Word2007');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Ругается на первую же строчку: `$template->setValue('family', $data['client']['family']);`

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid error type specified
>
> Filename: phpword/PHPWord.php
>
> Line Number: 226
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> setValue() on a non-object in
> Z:\home\cbonus.ru\www\application\controllers\bcard\cards.php
> on line 142

3 дня пытаюсь разобраться и решить проблему, но пока неудачно. Может кто подскажет в чем проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего, он просто не может найти файл. Укажите полный путь.